# Уменьшение частоты кадров в видео файле

Tags: python, opencv

Вопрос. Доброго времени суток. Для более быстрого анализа видео приходиться изменять количество кадров в видео.

Я пользуюсь двумя модулям для этого, первый разбивает видео на отдельные кадры выбранные с нужной частотой, второй обратно склеивает в видео но с уже более низким количеством кадров.

Подскажите как можно более просто и быстро сделать тоже самое. В моем случае больше всего неудобств доставляет ручной ввод конечного и начального номера кадра при склейки.

## Модуль раскадровки

```
import cv2
#Настройка файла
videoFile = r"D:\274.avi" #Путь к файлу
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)
success,image = vidcap.read()

#Настраиваемые параметры 

seconds = 0.1 #время 
fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) # Получаем кадры в секунду
multiplier = fps * seconds

# Запускаем процесс

while success:
    frameId = int(round(vidcap.get(1))) #текущий номер кадра, округленный 
    success, image = vidcap.read()

if frameId % multiplier == 0:
    cv2.imwrite(r"C:\Users\321\frame%d.jpg" % frameId, image)

vidcap.release()
print ("Завершено")
```

## Модуль сборки

```
import sys
import cv2  
import os
frames= r'C:\Users\321'
frames = [ os.path.join(frames, 'frame{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(5,3750) ]# Путь к скриншотам. Нужно указать начальный номер кадра и конечный. 
 Смотрим в папке.
frame = cv2.imread(frames[0]) 
writer = cv2.VideoWriter(
'274.mp4',
cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'),   # кодек
25.0,  # fps
(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]),  # ширина, высота кадра
isColor=len(frame.shape) > 2)
for frame in map(cv2.imread, frames):
writer.write(frame)
writer.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось примерно так. Добавил поиск самого первого и самого последнего файла, очистил их названия и перевел в числовое значение. Работает.

```
import sys
import cv2  
import os

#Настройка файла
videoFile = r"D:\27 4.avi" #Путь к файлу
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)
success,image = vidcap.read()

#Настраиваемые параметры 

seconds = 0.1 #время 
fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) # Получаем кадры в секунду
multiplier = fps * seconds

# Запускаем процесс

while success:
    frameId = int(round(vidcap.get(1))) #текущий номер кадра, округленный 
    success, image = vidcap.read()

    if frameId % multiplier == 0:
         cv2.imwrite(r"C:\Users\321\%d.jpg" % frameId, image)

 vidcap.release()

 frames= r'C:\Users\321' # Путь к вашей папке
 # Получим список имен всего содержимого папки
 # и превратим их в абсолютные пути
 dir_list = [os.path.join(frames, x) for x in os.listdir(frames)]

 if dir_list:
     # Создадим список из путей к файлам и дат их создания.
     date_list = [[x, os.path.getctime(x)] for x in dir_list]

     # Отсортируем список по дате создания в обратном порядке и в обычном порядке
    sort_date_list_min = sorted(date_list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=False)
    sort_date_list_max = sorted(date_list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    # Уберем путь, отстанется только нужное нам число из имени файла
    a=int(os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(sort_date_list_min[0][0])[0]))
    b=int(os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(sort_date_list_max[0][0])[0]))  


 frames = [ os.path.join(frames, '{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(a, b) ]
 frame = cv2.imread(frames[0]) 
 writer = cv2.VideoWriter( r'C:\Users\VIDEO\KICaserfsdfsd.mp4',
    cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'),   # кодек
    25.0,  # fps
    (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]),  # ширина, высота кадра
    isColor=len(frame.shape) > 2)
for frame in map(cv2.imread, frames):
    writer.write(frame)
writer.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print ("Завершено")
```